# Counting present entities on each day given each entities present date range (optimization)

Tags: python, algorithm, pandas, optimization

An entity is present for a given continuous date range. Assuming a collection of such entities, calculate the count of present entities on each day from the oldest start date to the newest end date in the collection.

For example, consider the following dataset which contains one entity per row.

```
        start         end
0  2016-12-24  2017-01-01
1  2016-12-26  2016-12-31
2  2016-12-27  2016-12-31
3  2016-12-27  2016-12-29
4  2016-12-27  2016-12-31
```

The expected output should be:

```
            entity_count
2016-12-24           1.0
2016-12-25           1.0
2016-12-26           2.0
2016-12-27           5.0
2016-12-28           5.0
2016-12-29           5.0
2016-12-30           4.0
2016-12-31           4.0
2017-01-01           1.0
```

**Does a solution exist that performs better than the naive approach provided below?**

naive approach (iterates by entity)

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def sample(n=100, rng=50, dt=datetime.date.today(), seed=True):
    if seed:
        np.random.seed(30)
    for i in range(n):
        start = dt - datetime.timedelta(np.random.randint(rng))
        end = dt + datetime.timedelta(np.random.randint(rng))
        yield (start, end)

def agg_rng(df, start, end):
    idx = pd.date_range(df[start].min(), df[end].max())
    base = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(len(idx)), idx, ['entity_count'])
    for i, s in df.iterrows():
        idx = pd.date_range(s[start], s[end])
        entity = pd.DataFrame(np.ones(len(idx)), idx, ['entity_count'])
        base = base.add(entity, fill_value=0)
    return base

# generates the above example
data = pd.DataFrame([x for x in sample(5, 5)], columns=['start', 'end'])
agg_rng(data, 'start', 'end')
```

With 10,000 entities and a range of +/- 1,000 days `agg_rng` takes 16s.

```
data = pd.DataFrame([x for x in sample(10000, 1000)], columns=['start', 'end'])
agg_rng(data, 'start', 'end')
```

Comment: Sorry , the question is not clear . can you please post the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First order of business, convert columns to datetime:

```
data = data.apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

Second order of business, create an index of days from min date to max date.

```
v = data.values
tidx = pd.date_range(v.min(), v.max())
```

---

Now use numpy broadcasting to evaluate what's greater than/less than what and count.

```
data = data.apply(pd.to_datetime)

v = data.values
tidx = pd.date_range(v.min(), v.max())

starts = data.start.values[:, None] <= tidx.values
ends = data.end.values[:, None] >= tidx.values

pd.Series((starts & ends).sum(0), tidx)

2016-12-24    1
2016-12-25    1
2016-12-26    2
2016-12-27    5
2016-12-28    5
2016-12-29    5
2016-12-30    4
2016-12-31    4
2017-01-01    1
Freq: D, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hi @piRSquared, I wasn't able to produce the expected outcome with this code.

Comment: @BMW I've updated my answer, apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks! Nice solution.